# how java inner class objects exists in the memory heap?

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory, inner-classes

```
class Outer {
    int o = 10;
    class Inner {
        int i = 20;
    }    
}

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Outer o = new Outer();
        Outer.Inner oi = o.new Inner();
    }
}
```

when we creating an inner class object through a outer class object how they both associate with each other in the heap ?

Answer (score 4):

Basically the compiler implicitly creates a constructor taking a reference to the outer class, which is stored in a hidden field. So your code is *somewhat* like this:

```
class Outer {
    int o = 10;
    static class Inner {
        private final Outer outer;
        int i = 20;

        Inner(Outer outer) {
           this.outer = outer;
        }
    }    
}

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Outer o = new Outer();
        Outer.Inner oi = new Outer.Inner(o);
    }
}
```

(Note that I've converted the inner class into a static nested class.)

Comment: why convert the inner class into a static nested class ? thank you for the answer :)

Comment: @KalhanoToressPamuditha: Precisely to remove the complication of inner classes - the point is that an *inner* class has the implicit constructor and field, but a *static nested* class doesn't. So you can sort of think of it as the compiler converting your original code to this code, and then compiling only being aware of static nested classes.

Comment: is last statement of your code correct ? or is it `Outer.Inner oi = new Outer.Inner(o);`

Comment: @KalhanoToressPamuditha: Sorry, yes - fixed.

Comment: still i don't understand why inner class converted in to static ? is it add by the compiler ? then why we don't allowed to put static members in the inner class ?

Comment: @KalhanoToressPamuditha: Because otherwise there'd be *two* references to the `Outer` instance - one implicit (because it's an inner class) and the one I added. Imagine there were two versions of Java - one with inner classes, and one with only static nested classes. I've converted your code from the first version to the second version.

Comment: @KalhanoToressPamuditha: Your comment still isn't clear, but the conversion I've performed is *just* to show you how the reference to the outer class is passed in and stored, because that's what your question was about.

Answer (score 0):

I think Jon Skeet has illustrated the point that logical inner classes (i.e. which are contained within any outer class) have a reference to outer class.

However, I'd like to present it differently. As per the standard book "Java Programming Language, 4th Edition" by James Gosling and co:

Non-static nested classes are called **inner classes**. Non-static class members are associated with instances of a class. Non-static fields are instance variables.

Similarly, an inner class is also (usually) associated with an "instance" of a class, or more specifically an "instance of an inner class" is associated with
 an *instance of its enclosing class*.

So, if objects of outer level classes are present in heap, the associated inner class objects would also be present.

However, I don't think statically nested classes will necessarily be present in the heap IN ASSOCIATION WITH objects of outer class. They are just like any other outer independent class.